# The minimum value of the polynomial $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$ is

Tags: calculus

The minimum value of the polynomial $f(x) = x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$ is....

$f'(x) = 4x^{3} + 18x^{2} + 22x +6$
I am not able to find its roots to get minimum value of function.

Without any graph plotter or any online tool, can I find its minimum value$?$

Comment: By inspection, $f'(x)=0$ has a root at $x=-\frac 32$. So, long division gives a quadratic in $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: It is $$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+1=(1+3x+x^2)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=(y-1)(y+1)=y^2-1\ge-1$$ where $x(x+3)+1=y$

The equality occurs if $$0=y=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, there *is* a [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula), analogous to the quadratic formula for finding the roots of a generic cubic polynomial.  But it's a mess, and I wouldn't expect anyone to have it memorized.

Sometimes—and this is the case here—one gets lucky and a rational root exists.  If a rational root does exist, it is necessarily of the form $p/q$, where $p$ is a divisor of the constant term and $q$ a divisor of the leading coefficient (see: [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)).  Knowing this, all rational roots can be found via trial-and-error.  With a rational root $\alpha$ in hand, one can proceed by computing $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x- \alpha}$ using polynomial long division, which yields a quadratic polynomial.  The remaining roots can then be found by applying the quadratic formula to this polynomial.

---

These approaches work in generality, but this is not to say that an easier method does not exist for this specific case; see other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Note the symmetry of the product and shift the origin to the center of the symmetry, $x=-\frac32+u$, then
$$
x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)=\left(u^2-\frac94\right)\left(u^2-\frac14\right)
$$
Now this product can be expressed as the difference of two squares, $ab=\frac14[(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2]$, which gives
$$
...=\left(u^2-\frac54\right)^2-1
$$
This now is obviously minimal if and only if $u^2=\frac54$